# Win32 API equivalent to POSIX fpathconf()?

Tags: winapi, filesystems, posix

Does the Win32 API have an equivalent to POSIX fpathconf(), for example to figure out what the maximum length of a file name can be for a specific mounted filesystem? Or whether the filesystem for a given path supports symlinks?

Answer (score 4):

Look at [`GetVolumeInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationw):

> Retrieves information about the file system and volume associated with the specified root directory.

In this case, the `lpMaximumComponentLength` and `lpFileSystemFlags` parameters can be used to help you determine what you are looking for.

Also see [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file), in particular the sections on [Paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#paths) and [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation)