# Win32 API equivalent to POSIX pathconf() _PC_MIN_HOLE_SIZE (minimum sparse file hole size)?

Tags: winapi, sparse-file

What is the Win32 API equivalent to POSIX pathconf() _PC_MIN_HOLE_SIZE, i.e. how can I query the minimum sparse file hole size for a specific path in a filesystem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76973107/win32-api-equivalent-to-posix-fpathconf?rq=2 'd already answered it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Win32 API equivalent to POSIX fpathconf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76973107/win32-api-equivalent-to-posix-fpathconf)